# How to initiate opening a file (image) from a QT UI menubar (top menu)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a C++ project that is using QT4.  I've used QT Designer to build my form, and in the top bar I have `"File -> Open Image"`.  The "`Open Image`" piece is designated by the QT Designer as a `QObject` with `objectName: actionOpen_Image`.

How do I go from a user pressing this `QObject`, to selecting an image and getting its path so I can load it?

Comment: That's a broad question! You might have a look at this Qt sample for a head start regarding signals/slots and standard dialogs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dialogs-standarddialogs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, menu items are [QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html) objects - if you can get your object to be an action, that would be a good first step.

`QAction`s have a signal [triggered](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#triggered) which is emitted when selected by a user.  This signal can be connected to a `slot` which can be [part of an existing `QObject` or custom-defined](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

To create and object with a `slot`, the following example may be helpful:

```
class MyClass : QObject{
Q_OBJECT //<---macro which flags the class for the Meta-Object Compiler(moc) tool
public:
  MyClass(QObject* parent=):QObject(parent){}
public slots: //<--- also for the moc tool to handle
  void mySlot(){
    //custom behavior
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(/*args*/);
  }
};
```

Here, the [QFileDialog class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QFileDialog.html) is used (via a `static` method) to get the name of a file.  You can set filters for file types and other useful properties, and the dialog will use the native file-dialog of whatever operating system you're working with.

Use the `connect(QObject* sender, SIGNAL, QObject* receiver, SLOT)` method to connect the `QAction::triggered` signal to the `slot` you wish to be activated.

Actual implementation is up to you of course, hope this can get you started.